# Msbuild EXEC and Copying output to destination folders

Tags: xml, msbuild

I have a exe which generates .xml file based on some logic and I am running this exe as part of MsBuild Command task like below.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <XMLBuilderConsole Include="XMLBuilder.exe"></XMLBuilderConsole>
</ItemGroup>

<Exec Command='"@(XMLBuilderConsole )"' 
     ConsoleToMSBuild="true">
    <Output TaskParameter="ConsoleOutput" PropertyName="OutputOfExec" />
 <!-- Copy o/p of this command i.e. XML to some destination-->
</Exec>
```

XML's get successfully created but now I need to run this XML Builder command in loop. What I am looking for is, is it possible to somehow get hold of Output i.e. every XML that is getting generated in EXEC command and copy it to different destinations based on some conditions. I tried using OutPut property but no luck. Any other advice or way to achieve this?